# How to use icons in stead of text in Android tabs

Tags: android, menu, tabs, icons

I have been using text in my menu tabs since I built my application. But now I want to change the text into icons. The problem is, my application 'knows' which tab is selected, by the string of the tab. But now I changed the texts in icons, it cannot use tab.getText() anymore.

Any ideas how to solve this? I tried .getIcon() but it returns a different string every time.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Forgot about getPosition()! It's the solution for my problem.